# How do I return a compass heading in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, geolocation

I have looked around at a couple of methods on how to return a compass heading from `Javascript` and have found one method through `navigator.geolocation.watchposition`.

There is a value that should return a compass heading (coords.heading) but it only ever returns `null`.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((data) =>{
    console.log(data.coords.heading);
    lat = data.coords.latitude; //Lat and long values return correct coords
    long = data.coords.longitude;
    heading = data.coords.heading; //this value returns null
});
```

Is this method outdated or am I doing something wrong?

I have been testing this on an android device with chrome through a secure connection.

(I have looked at previous questions regarding this but I could only find ones from 2013 so I thought some things may have been deprecated since.)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates - Heading is null if the device is unable to provide heading

Comment: Ok, do I have to allow the browser to access my devices heading? (other than allowing the browser to share my location)

Comment: Are you sure your device is capable of providing that info?

Comment: I think so, the device I am testing on is a Galaxy A5 so its somewhat modern.

Comment: I was also able to download and use a compass app from the google play store on the device.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```